# Go: How can I create a global variable to hold anything?

Tags: go

I'm curious on how to create a global variable that can be assigned to be anything when the chance comes, here's my scenario:

I have to wait for an event that emits from a server that sends a populated struct, and I want to assign that to a variable the struct is created with:

```
func NewCS(client *thing.Thing) *structThing {

}
```

But the `*structThing` is not exported so I can't do

```
var cs *structThing

// Event finally ready
cs = NewCS(eventData)
```

because I get the error that `*structThing` is not exported.

So how else can I make `cs` a global variable?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just export `structThing`? I'm not entirely sure how to answer your question but I don't think what you're proposing is very sound. Your scoping is just incongruous. In the containing package you're exporting a method to return a type which you don't export. The two things are inherently coupled and therefor should have the same exported vs unexported status imo. While you may be able to work around this and do something more like what you're describing I think you'd save yourself a lot of trouble by just exporting `structThing`.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal it's mainly created through a function to avoid unintentionally setting the wrong properties on the struct which should only be done by the package it's self. But I might have to just export it I guess. Thanks.

Comment: One idea to work around that (and I haven't tested this concept so that's on you) would be to take the properties you don't want people touching, move them to another struct, embed that in `structThing` and don't export just that field. In `NewCS`' calling scope people can have the object with no problems, they just won't see those properties. Provide a method to return their values if they need to be accessed. If that idea doesn't work you could use the same concept but do it on a field by field basis.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal thanks I might just try that instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store it in an variable typed as an `interface{}`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type structThing struct {
    x int
}

func NewCS() *structThing {
    return &structThing{x: 1}
}

var cs interface{}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("cs is", cs)
    cs = NewCS()
    fmt.Println("cs is now", cs)
}
```

Which prints:

```
cs is <nil>
cs is now &{1}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ZW_6FRfDvE